# Set PDF title with Java and FOP

Tags: java, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I'm generating some PDF files using Apache FOP v0.94.

Can you please tell me how to set the PDF Document Properties like Title, Author, Keywords etc programmatically?

Googled a bit but didn't get any useful information.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also:
- http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/embedding.html#user-agent
- http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/metadata.html

Comment: Set the user agent properties as mentioned in http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/embedding.html#user-agent and it works!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#pdf-doc-properties) and [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.94/output.html#pdf-postprocess).

It says you should use [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) for post processing.